Can I have secrets that don't expire in Microsoft SSO via Azure Microsoft Entra ID?
In the Azure Portal, I create a resource Microsoft Entra ID and then add an app registration.
In the app registration I can specify redirect URIs for Microsoft logins (SSO) via "Authentication" for my .NET web app:
Authentication button on side bar
To use this this feature in my website, I currently use appsettings.json where I specify the client ID, tenant ID, and secret that I generate via the "Certificates and secrets":
Secrets on button on side bar
However the secrets expire and I need to regenerate new client secrets.
I am aware Azure has Managed Identities, but I'm not sure they're applicable in this case and there is something called "federated credentials". Is there a way to deploy a web app and not have to manage secrets/certificates as they expire?
What I tried:
Attempted to find if I could use Managed Identities but couldn't figure out how.
Tried to use federated certificates but from the error response it indicates I need to upload a certificate?

You can use SAML sso with EntraID, which has a certificate (which can be long term expired 3y+)

@ZivWeissmanwho waana use saml ? it is dead since ages ^^ also cert should be renewed max once per y

@user24802569 oauth protocol will require a client secret if you use the authorization code flow

which flow are you using ?

@Thomas I believe Authorization Code Flow, but can use any flow if I don't need to manage secrets and results in what I want i.e. let users sign into my app with their work email. It is a private facing app for work accounts only, managed by Microsoft.

As you mentioned, in general there are only two potential options for secretless approach: Managed Identity or Federated Credentials. But both are native for Azure stuff, not for reusing outside of Azure. I would look towards figuring out how to use Federated Credentials in your custom application. Basically, it's a trust from your application to Entra ID.

@VladDX I looked into Federated Credentials but found hassle of having to manage a certificate and provide this in a web app. I didn't want certificates or secrets as they both expire.

The best solution I came up with is that I can use this in my C# ASP.NET web app:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

and then in my config I don't need to use secrets and it allows me to login via the app registration created in Entra ID on my tenant, using only Application ID and Tenant ID.
